# sed and ln commands not working in rpm post install script

Tags: sed, centos, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm trying to build an RPM for our program and running into some issues.  I'm trying to run the `sed` and `ln` commands as a script in the postinstall/preremove and they don't seem to be making any changes.  We are using the maven rpm plugin to build the RPM.  I read somewhere that turning selinux off might help but it still doesn't work.  We are using CentOS 7.

from the pom.xml:

```
  <postinstallScriptlet>
    <script>sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' /path/to/file</script>
  </postinstallScriptlet>
  <preremoveScriptlet>
    <script>sed -i 's/bar/foo/g' /path/to/file</script>
  </preremoveScriptlet>
```

This works when I run it by hand but not as part of the rpm

Comment: maybe add `/path/to/sed -i ...` ? Good luck.

Comment: /path/to/sed  didn't fix it.

Comment: You did use `/usr/bin/sed` or the appropriate `/path/to/` ? Good luck.

Comment: yeah, I used /usr/bin/sed.

Answer (score 0):

That should work with fresh install. However it will not work when you are upgrading packages. Because of the ordering. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Scriptlet_Ordering

Rpm first call postinstallScriptlet of new package, install it, and then call preremoveScriptlet of old version of package and then remove the old version.
So you basically call `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' /path/to/file` immediatelly followed by `sed -i 's/bar/foo/g' /path/to/file`.

You likely want something like:

```
<preremoveScriptlet>
    <script>
if [ 0$1 -eq 0 ] ; then
  sed -i 's/bar/foo/g' /path/to/file
fi
</script>
  </preremoveScriptlet>
```

which will call the sed only if you are really uninstalling the package. And not during upgrades. Similary for post install scriptlet. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Syntax

Comment: The post install scriptlet doesn't even work with a fresh install.